# UITextField: when "Done" is shown in the keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I have working on implementing sign up screen, and there are three input fields and custom gender selection buttons below them. Now when first field becomes first responder then "Next" button is shown in the right bottom keyboard. Pressing "Next" moves to the second field, and the pressing it again moves to the third field and shows "Done".

I need to override and show "Next" instead "Done", so that a user could press it, I would close keyboard and scroll the screen a little bit so he would see he needs to select gender. Just trying to figure out what causes to show "Done" on last textField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```